# How to keep sshpass process in the background?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, sshpass

`sshpass -p '1234567*' ssh -L 1080:192.168.0.1:2222 admin@gateway.com -p 4422 -f -C -N`

The above code works on macOS (creating a 1080 tunnel to 192.168.0.1:2222 via gateway.com:4422 with username admin and password 1234567*).\

It doesn't work on Linux - the process seems to run and terminate immediately.

Comment: I've had the same issue. I wondered whether it was my router being weird (openwrt) but apparently not

Comment: Also see https://serverfault.com/questions/1001833/ssh-running-in-background-f-with-sshpass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `sshpass` + `ssh` is that `ssh` first authenticates the user, forks a child to handle the connection and then exits. But `sshpass` will pull the rug from under the child as soon as the parent `ssh` has exited, before the child had any chance to detach itself from the terminal (the pseudo-tty created by `sshpass`) and consequently it will be killed by a `SIGHUP` signal.

Therefore this would work:

`sshpass -p '1234567*' sh -c 'ssh -L 1080:192.168.0.1:2222 admin@gateway.com -p 4422 -f -C -N && sleep .1'`